# Does an election vote count towards your Stack Overflow vote count?

Tags: support, voting, moderator-election

I was wondering if a vote in the Moderator Primary Election counts towards the total daily vote limit on the site?

Comment: I think it won't count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No I don't believe it does.

As I've voted on numerous candidates and it doesn't show up in my profile under the votes section, therefore I'd assume it is handled completely separately as it should be.

Candidates are neither Questions or Answers so there is no reason for the votes to count towards your daily limit.

The proof from my profile if the above wasn't sufficient:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I've voted on around 20 candidates this morning, and on Stack Overflow I've cast 3 votes today, which you can see displayed:

Comment: those values are heavily cached and not really reliable until quite a few hours later (not disagreeing with your answer, just saying your proof isn't proof).

Comment: @TZHX the 3 votes I cast on SO were 20 mins or so prior to the screenshot, so they are accurate.